# How to resize the block of a column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a single column of a file having many blocks and the blocks are separated by the `>` symbol.

I want to resize all blocks to the same highest length by appending zero below them.

My file is given below:

`file.txt`

```
>
1.0
2.4
3.5
4.5
>
1.2
3.3
>
2.4
2.5
2.5
```

and my expected output is given below

```
>
1.0
2.4
3.5
4.5
>
1.2
3.3
0.0
0.0
>
2.4
2.5
2.5
0.0
```

I am trying to write a script, but it fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in `cat file.txt`
do
    awk '{print $1+0}' $file
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^>/){
     max=(max>val?max:val)
     val=""
     next
  }
  val++
  next
}
/^>/{
  if(FNR>1){
    while(count++<max){ print "0" }
  }
  count=""
  print
  next
}
{
  print
  count++
}
END{
  while(count++<max){ print "0" }
}'  Input_file  Input_file
```

For shown samples output will be as follows.

```
>
1.0
2.4
3.5
4.5
>
1.2
3.3
0
0
>
2.4
2.5
2.5
0
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                ##Checking condition if FNR==NR here.
  if($0~/^>/){                          ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
     max=(max>val?max:val)              ##Assigning max value as per max>val then assign it to max else keep it as val value.
     val=""                             ##Nullify val here.
     next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
  }
  val++                                 ##Increasing val with 1 here.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/{                                   ##Checking condition if line starts with >
  if(FNR>1){                            ##Checking condition if this is not first line.
    while(count++<max){ print "0" }     ##Printing 0 till count is equal to max.
  }
  count=""                              ##Nullify count here.
  print                                 ##Printing current line here.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print                                 ##Printing current line here.
  count++                               ##Increasing count with 1 here.
}
END{                                    ##Starting END block of this program from here.
    while(count++<max){ print "0" }     ##Printing 0 till count is equal to max.
}' Input_file Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: if my  input is >
1.0
>
1.2
3.3
>
2.4
2.5
2.5  then it doesnot work

Comment: @sion, answers will be always given as per shown samples only. So please try to add samples of input and expected output in your very first question itself to avoid confusions later.

Comment: ur script is based on the length of first block....but i need to resize the based on highest block length of a given file

Comment: can u please modify it

Comment: @sion, No script is looking HIGHEST block size in whole file, if you go through explanation you will see, I have explained it, first read is for that only. First read its getting maximum block length and 2nd read its printing accordingly.

Comment: @sion, could you please check if your Input_file have control M characters in it? By doing `cat -v Input_file` once? That could cause problems, let me know if you see them.

Comment: then will it work if my input is > 1.0 > 1.2 3.3 > 2.4 2.5 2.5

Comment: it gives me output >
1.0
0
>
1.2
3.3
>
2.4
2.5
2.5

Comment: but it should be 1.0 0 0 > 1.2 3.3 0 > 2.4 2.5 2.5

Comment: @sion, As mentioned my previous comments. Could you please check if your Input_file have control M characters in it? By doing `cat -v Input_file` once? That could cause problems, let me know if you see them.

Comment: after typing cat -v file it gives   >
1.0
>
1.2
3.3
>
2.4
2.5
2.5

Comment: @sion,its not clear without CODE TAGS in comments, please do add them in comments using backticks so that they look like this `bla bla bla` see difference between this in CODE TAGS one and normal text.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if (/^>/) c=0
    if (++c>m) m=c
    next
}
END {while (n-->0) print "0.0"}
/^>/{while (n-->0) print "0.0"; n=m} {n--}
1
' file file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this *single-pass* `awk` also:

```sh
awk '$0==">"{if (c && c>max) max=c; ++n; c=0; next} {r[n][++c]=$0} END {for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {print ">"; for (j=1; j<=max; ++j) print (r[i][j] == "" ? "0.0" : r[i][j])}}' file

>
1.0
2.4
3.5
4.5
>
1.2
3.3
0.0
0.0
>
2.4
2.5
2.5
0.0
```

To make it more readable:

```
awk '$0==">" {
   if (c && c>max)
      max = c
   ++n
   c = 0
   next
}
{
   r[n][++c] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
      print ">"
      for (j=1; j<=(max>c?max:c); ++j)
         print (r[i][j] == "" ? "0.0" : r[i][j])
   }
}' file
```